# Show Rating bar in google marker

Tags: android, google-maps

I have been trying to put a rating bar into my google marker, yet failed to find a way to do it.  i followed this example [Using Layout as Custom Marker](http://www.nasc.fr/android/android-using-layout-as-custom-marker-on-google-map-api/).
is there any way i can put a rating bar inside the google marker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to place your rating bar inside an `Info Window`:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/infowindows